# How can I convert a decimal number to hex in VIM?

Tags: vim

I have this column in a file I'm editing in VIM:

```
16128
16132
16136
16140
# etc...
```

And I want to convert it to this column:

```
0x3f00
0x3f04
0x3f08
0x3f0c
# etc...
```

How can I do this in VIM?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use `printf` (analogous to C's `sprintf`) with the `\=` command to handle the replacement:

```
:%s/\d\+/\=printf("0x%04x", submatch(0))
```

**Details**:

- `:%s/\d\+/` : Match one or more digits (`\d\+`) on any line (`:%`) and substitute (`s`).
- `\=` : for each match, replace with the result of the following expression:
- `printf("0x%04x",` : produce a string using the format `"0x%04x"`, which corresponds to a literal `0x` followed by a four digit (or more) hex number, padded with zeros.
- `submatch(0)` : The result of the complete match (i.e. the number).

For more information, see:

```
:help printf()
:help submatch()
:help sub-replace-special
:help :s
```

Comment: works well, be aware that if your integers contain negative values, you'll need it preface your search appropriately `s/-\?\d\+/\=printf("0x%08x", submatch(0))` and remove the extra `0xffff`s as required: eg `s/0xffffffff/0x` for 32bit.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way:

```
:rubydo $_ = '0x%x' % $_
```

Or:

```
:perldo $_ = sprintf '0x%x', $_
```

This is a bit less typing and you avoid a level of quoting / shell escaping that you'd get if you did this via `:!`.  You need Perl / Ruby support compiled into your Vim.

Comment: And it's easier than remembering how to use Vimscript, if (like most people) you use it far less often than Perl and Ruby.

Answer (score 5):

another way, to pass it to awk

```
awk '{printf "0x%x\n",$1}' file
```

Answer (score 5):

Select (VISUAL) the block of lines that contains the numbers, and then:

```
:!perl -ne 'printf "0x\%x\n", $_'
```

Comment: Why use perl when Vim has an internal printf?

Answer (score 1):

To convert a decimal into hexadecimal, use the command

```
:echo printf("%x", decimal)
```

This results in hexadecimal equivalent of decimal being displayed.

Example:

```
:echo printf("%x", 61444)
```

f004 (equivalent of 61444) is displayed.

This will not find and replace 61444 in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a custom command in .vimrc for this purpose:

```
vnoremap <leader>x "yy:r! printf "= 0x\%x" $((<C-r>y))<CR>kJ$
```

It copies the current selection to a register, runs a printf shell command to convert the number to hex, and inserts the result on the same line. The benefit of using `$(( ... ))` is that it makes use of bash's built-in arithmetic calculation capabilities, so you can select things like `0xdead + 0x1337` and get:

`0xdead + 0x1337 = 0xf1e4`

To run it on a full column, you can create a macro that selects the number at point, e.g., with `viW` and run `<leader> x`. Then, you can select all the lines and run the macro on each line using `norm @a`, assuming your macro was saved to register a.